# Cannot mount external HDD. Help!

Tags: hard-drive, filesystem

I connected my external HDD to my TV and the TV did not recognize it. After that I can't open it on my computer any more.

I tried `fsck` which kept asking more and more questions. Fearing that I would make the data impossible to retrieve by giving wrong answers (y/n), I stopped in the middle. The error message has changed since (it used to be about invalid fs type)

It wouldn't open on Windows either (Win 7 on VM). I believe the original format was NTFS

Current error:

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/[username omitted]/28bc82aa-d4bd-459e-b071-16839167a6da: Command-line `mount -t "ext4" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid" "/dev/sdb1" "/media/.../28bc82aa-d4bd-459e-b071-16839167a6da"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: /dev/sdb1: can't read superblock
```

The data is very important to me and I don't have any other copy of some of it

Comment: What does `fdisk -l` output? How many partitions are there on the hard drive? It may just be the first one causing the trouble *(which is a problem if it only has one partition)*.

Comment: Two partitions - the second one is fine

Comment: I think the first issue right now is that the OS thinks its filesystem is ext4 whereas the filesystem is NTFS

Comment: If that is the case you may just need to use `mount` - added it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Manually mounting the file-system should work - just use the `mount` command:

It uses these parameters:
`mount -t type device dir`

So run this:

`mount -t ntfs DEVICE_LOCATION PLACE_TO_MOUNT_IT`

Here is an example:

`mount -t ntfs /dev/sdb1 /mnt`

For more information run `man mount`

---

Check it with GParted - `sudo apt-get install gparted` then `gparted`. http://gparted.sourceforge.net/

This will show the formatting of your disk, and whether it has any data on it - it can also repair the disk if necessary.

[image]

Backing it to an image would also be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Since filesystem manipulation causes always risk of data loss I recommend to make a backup before doing anything else:  [Data-Recovery: Imaging a damaged device, filesystem or drive](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery#Imaging_a_damaged_device.2C_filesystem_or_drive)